# VS 2013 Ultimate, KB2829760 error on update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013, failed-installation

I am attempting to install Update 4 (VS2013.4.exe) over the Update 3 and get an error KB2829760, the hash value is incorrect.

i had cleaned my PC and fix registry using CCleaner but it is not helping

Log file: https://paste.ee/p/hqRxk